# .htaccess throwing my website in disarray

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mapping

Something odd is happening to my website. I added a DirectoryIndex wp/index.php to my .htaaccess. It works fine in that my home page is now index.php however there was a side effect. Now, when I go to my website and I click a link, although the url is correct it doesn't load the page. Instead it hits shows the directory. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: put your htaccess code here if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix at 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
Wasn't what I thought would do the trick but it did. Still wondering why the DirectoryIndex didn't work if someone has a solution for it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ foo/bar [L]
```